# Property 'subscribe' does not exist on type 'typeof Observable'

Tags: angular, rxjs

Here is my service file

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import {Subject} from 'rxjs/Subject';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Observable';
import * as io from 'socket.io-client';

export class chatService{
    private url = 'http://localhost:8000'
    private socket:any;

    sendMessage(message:string){
        this.socket.emit('add-message', message);
    }
    getMessages(){
        let observable = new Observable(( observer:any)=>{
            this.socket = io(this.url);
            this.socket.on('message',(data:any)=>{
                observer.next(data);
            });
            return () => {
                this.socket.disconnect();
            }
        })
        return Observable;
    }
}
```

And here is my subscribe method showing the error

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import {chatService} from '../../services/chat.service';
import { OnInit, OnDestroy } from '@angular/core/src/metadata/lifecycle_hooks';
import { Message } from '@angular/compiler/src/i18n/i18n_ast';
import * as io from 'socket.io-client';
@Component({
  moduleId:module.id,
  selector: 'chat',
  templateUrl: `chat.componets.html`,
})
export class chatComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {connection: any;
 name = 'Angular'; 
messages: any = [];
message: string;
 constructor(private _chatService:chatService){

 }
 sendMessage(){
   this._chatService.sendMessage(this.message);
   this.message = '';
 }
 ngOnInit(){
  this.connection = this._chatService.getMessages().subscribe(message=> {
      console.log(message);
      this.messages.push(message);
  });
 }
 ngOnDestroy(){
   this.connection.unsubscribe();
 }
}
```

In service file in which i have to call `getMessage()` and when am going to subscribe the method in the other class where i am calling that service method `getMessage()`. It shows the error

> [ts] Property 'subscribe' does not exist on type 'typeof Observable'

And another error says

> [ts] Parameter 'message' implicitly has an 'any' type. (parameter)
>   message: any

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you have a small typo. Change this:

```
return Observable;
```

to this:

```
return observable;
```